# Databinding foreign key contraints to a form

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, combobox

In my control I am setting the datacontext of an items control which generates a control like this. this is the data template...
Basicaly, as you can see, I am Binding single values of en EF entity to controls.

```
<Grid Name="grdRoles" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.4*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--Subject-->

                <Label Content="Podmodul" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="label0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                <Label Content="ID:" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Ime:" Grid.Row="2" Height="28" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Opis:" Grid.Row="3" Height="28" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <!--Expander-->
                <Label Content="Modul:" Grid.Row="5" Height="28" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Dopuštenja:" Grid.Row="6" Height="28" Name="label10" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Stanje:" Grid.Row="7" Height="28" Name="label11" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                <TextBox    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=ID, Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False" />
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                <Expander Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="50, 5, 5, 5" Background="DarkGray">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <Label Content="Definicija:" Grid.Row="6" Height="28" Name="label9" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Expander.Content>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.4*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Content="ClassName:" Grid.Row="0" Height="28" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <Label Content="AssemblyName:" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" Name="label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <Label Content="NameSpace:" Grid.Row="2" Height="28" Name="label8" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <Label Content="Primaran:" Grid.Row="3" Height="28" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                            <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=ClassName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=AssemblyName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=NameSpace, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsPrimary, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Expander.Content>
                </Expander>

                <ComboBox   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Height="25"  />
                <WrapPanel  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Height="25"  />
                <CheckBox   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Height="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path=active, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**My problem is the following...**

I also have (at the end of the grid), this one combobox. I would like to have it binded to another EF Dataset (DB-table). When I select a value, the key should be automaticly set to the object that is databound. You see my point.

I know that there are hundreds of ways. triggers, DependantObject, codebehind... *What would be recomended.*

Comment: Hi. You could use a `ObjectDataProvider` within a the `ResourceDictionary` of your control. Then, within the `ComboBox`you can get the SelectedValuePath of which you would want the Foreign Key ID. Take a look at this example if this is what your looking for, hope this helps!:) http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/06/08/synch-a-combobox-in-wpf-with-foreign-keys.aspx

Comment: I always wonder, why WPF questions contains these huge pieces of markup, instead of minimal samples, reproducing the problem? Do you really believe, that anybody is happy to dig into your xml, which is somehow (you don't tell this) filled with data?

Comment: I digg you completly. from expirience I can say that if reduce the markup or simplify, you either get crappy suggestions that do not solve the problem, but solve the situation, or .... you find someone who will ask you to paste the whole thing.